# ComponentArt grid; javaScript; Aspx MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, componentart

I have a ComponentArt grid that I'm editing with a pop editing dialog.  I pass values between the grid and the dialog using javascript.  All was well until I put the page containing the grid inside a MasterPage; I got some errors because of naming containers and fixed them, but it looks like ComponentArt's DataGrid is still looking for something it can't find, because it's blowing up in their javascript.

Question: Has anyone had a ComponentArt DataGrid blow up inside a master page before, and if so, what did you do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue with ComponentArt Grids inside other controls, having to do with the dialog animation.  ComponentArt representative:

> This sounds like a known bug with the
>   dialog (D6098 in our system)- the live
>   animation type can error if the
>   control is within a control (say, a
>   user control, or in your case a
>   content control). Until the bug is
>   resolved you'll need to change the
>   animation type. I'm very sorry for the
>   trouble.

[Here's the forum post.](http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/p/61111/98869.aspx#98869)

Meanwhile, it looks like changing the animation is the only fix.